# \verb content going out of the page

Tags: xetex, line-breaking, verbatim

The `\verb` data is going out of the page.

```
\begin{itemize}
\item 
\verb |Now is the winter of our discontent Use the sample text below, or else you can replace it by typing over or pasting in your own block of text.|
\end{itemize}
```

ouput:
[image]

what is solution for this?

Comment: Welcome! Do you *need* `\verb` to begin with? That's for cases where you need to typeset special characters such as `{}\&#` Otherwise `\texttt{<text>}` is what you want.

Comment: This command and verbatim environment are to show the without any posterior formatting, including spaces and line breaks. It is the only case when LaTeX becomes a truly  WYSIWYG program, and you cannot use verbatim text anywhere. So, do not use it like a switch a monospaced font. Use `\verb` only when show the text "as is" is a must, for instance, to show a LaTeX command as `\LaTeX{}`, but even then, it could be better use \texttt and type the  command as `\textbackslash LaTeX\{\}`.

Comment: what if the \verb |......text......|  is a text of more than 1 line?
How to break those text as per line.

Comment: @KomalRumade Can you please show the ***real*** case you have to solve?

Comment: @egreg I want the line break in the text if the text goes beyond one line. Specifally for \verb added content.
In the above scrrenshot,  It will takes only single line text rest content gets lost.

Comment: @KomalRumade The text you show ***doesn't*** need `\verb`; just `\texttt{...}` around it is sufficient, if you want a monospaced font. That's why I'm asking for the *real* text you have.

Comment: @egreg I want to write the installation setup, thats the reason I want to use \verb

Comment: @egreg I also want to treat the special character as it is, So verb will be best practice.
I tried to use texttt but for this i need to treat the special character separately.
Also it ignore spaces.

Comment: @KomalRumade Why not showing the real text, so we can do better suggestions?

Comment: `\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{scrartcl}

\begin{document}

check with 
\verb|sudo docker info|
 if above entered settings are dispalyed, e.g. "Live Restore Enabled: true". If not, restart the docker engine service with 
\verb|sudo systemctl restart docker.service|

\end{document}`

Comment: @egreg this is just a small part of code i shared.

Comment: @egreg I have such multiple lines of code in latex which has same problem.

Comment: @KomalRumade I see no special character needing `\verb` in the example you provide: `\mbox{\texttt{sudo docker info}}` would do as well with no line break allowed; if you want to allow line breaks, remove the `\mbox` around `\texttt`.

Comment: @egreg Thank you for your help. Actually my data is coming from html and i m processing that in python and then converting it to latex.  So thats why i am asking for line break in verb.
`Is there any plugin or package which automatically break the text as per line lengh?`

Comment: There is automatic line-breaking neither with `\verb|...|` nor with `\begin{verbatim}...\end{verbatim}` because that's against the gist of verbatim-mode which is typesetting text as it is typed in the .tex-file. Probably one of the packages [listings](https://ctan.org/pkg/listings) or [minted](https://ctan.org/pkg/minted) provides what you need. E.g., the package listings brings along keys `breaklines=true/false` and `breakatwhitespace=true/false` but I don't know if they work only for listings-environment or also for `\lstinline`.

Answer (score 1):

If you like bad practice split your text into arguments of several `\verb`-commands separated by `\allowbreak` while `\sloppy`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item \sloppy
\verb|The Eastern world, it is explodin' |\allowbreak
\verb|Violence flarin', bullets loadin' |\allowbreak
\verb|You're old enough to kill but not for votin' |\allowbreak
\verb|You don't believe in war, but what's that gun you're totin'? |\allowbreak
\verb|And even the Jordan river has bodies floatin' |\allowbreak
\verb|You don't believe we're on the eve of destruction |\allowbreak
\verb|No no, you don't believe we're on the eve of destruction |
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  While this works, that's not a good example, since it's verse.  And that's one of the few places where using `\\ ` is acceptable, and in fact, preferable.

Comment: what if the \verb |......text......|  is a text of more than 1 line?
How to break those text as per line.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `verbatim` environment.

```
% verbatimprob.tex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Some regular text.

\begin{verbatim}
  A verbatim line
Another line
And an even longer one.
\end{verbatim}

Followed by nornmal text.
\end{document}
```

[image]